# The Xcode code signing identity changes after Xcode files checked in are then checked out of SVN

Tags: ios, xcode

Within Xcode if I set the code signing identity to some profile, lets call it A, then check the  project file into source control (SVN). 
Then if I check the project out onto another machine then I am finding that the profile that is set within XCode has changed from A to B. So it seems Xcode itself is picking which profile is being used and not what I set it to when the source code was checked in. I have to go and manually change it to what it should be.

This happens if I set the profile on machine X then check it out on machine Y, or vice versa.

Is XCode storing the profiles used in some local file which doesn't get automatically shared as opposed to a global file (like schemes, where you have to explicitly share them).

Why is XCode not using the profile that was set when the project was checked into source control?

I've not encountered this problem before, I've also updated to the latest Xcode, I don't know if that is related or just co-incidental.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode looks for the selected code signing identity in your keychain. Make sure the keychain in each account you are using has the same certificate/key pairs.

Comment: If I set the profile manually then it will build on both machines - thus the signing identity must be present in the keychain else it would fail to build.

Comment: Xcode stores provisioning profiles in "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"

Comment: You can find them in the Organizer window, Devices tab, Library heading, Provisoning Profiles - control click on the profile and select Reveal in Finder

Comment: Yes there are there. Everything is installed properly on each machine, everything builds properly on each machine. When Xcode is checked out all the profiles are available in Organizer. Just which profile was last used is not being remembered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected "Automatic Profile selector" in your project settings. If YES then XCode will pick the provisioning profile automatically. At times it may not be the correct profile or profile that you want. Verify that.

Comment: No I haven't selected that.

Comment: Also you generally don't checkin the scheme with the user preferences. You should only checkin the shared scheme settings.

Comment: The shared scheme is named something like this "xcshareddata" and user schemes are named like this "xcuserdata". Make sure that you have only checked in "xcshareddata" and NOT "xcuserdata".

Comment: xcshareddata files were being committed, but removing them does not solve the problem. But anyway, aren't the schemes which are used in the project setting stored in the .pbxproj files?

Comment: xcshareddata should be commited. xcuserdata should NOT be. And yes they are part of the .pbxproj file but if you just checkin that it will checkin xcuserdata as well.

Comment: I wrote my previous comment the wrong way round. I am checking in xcshareddata but not xcuserdata.